# Not able to read javascript files through localhost

Tags: javascript, apache, ubuntu, localhost

I have Ubuntu 15.04 and i am working on a project using bootstrap i have kept the files in "/var/www/html", none of my files are able to access the javascript files when the page is rendered from Localhost. But I have tried to render same file from a desktop or home the Javascript files work fine.

Comment: You probably have a permission issue for the files that not is accessible from within a HTML page.

Comment: can you check if the files are owned by apache or www-host. I guess they are owned by root which is why Apache could not read them .

Comment: I have have changed the file permissions of all the files to 777 using chmod but still the issue exists

Comment: "none of my files are able to access the javascript files", what do you mean?

Comment: the .html and .php files are are not able to access the javascript files

Comment: First things first, check the links are correct. We can't debug this without seeing your code and file structure. If the links are correct and permissions allow execution, check you haven't disabled JS in the browser.

Comment: Open the Developer Tools in your browser. Open the Network tab. Look at the URLs that are being requested. Look at the response you are getting. There isn't much that can be done to resolve this (short of guesswork) until you find out *why* the browser can't access the files.

Comment: Show the HTML code where you try to load the js file please.

Answer (score -1):

You Should open the .html files using from a server like if you are using apache you can use localhost/yourfilepath.html. Otherwise External JS files will not open.

Comment: Telling the OP to do something which (a) They are doing already and (b) Doesn't work isn't helpful.